# Trying to identify this piece - 2x2 flat bit with a longer rounded part with ridges

Tags: part-identification

I’m trying (and  failing) to identify this piece for my son

What would you call this?

[image: 2x2 flat bit with a longer rounded part with ridges]

Answer (score 5):

That would be [Engine, Strakes, 2 x 2 Thin Top Plate](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4229).

[image: part render]

It appears in a small number of [Classic Space sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=4229&colorID=9&in=A).

Comment: It's hard to tell from the image, but it could be either Light Gray, or Light Bluish Gray as in [these two sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=4229&colorID=86)

Comment: The part seems to be slightly dented, which IMHO is a sign of its age. That's why I'm assuming old Light Gray.